# Flight Path by shapely LineString is not correct

Tags: matplotlib, gis, geospatial, geopandas, shapely

I want to connect airplanes in origin (lat_1 lon_1) to dest(lat_2 lon_2). I use [these](https://zenodo.org/record/5764012#.YboD1NLP21s) data.

|  | callsign | latitude_1 | longitude_1 | latitude_2 | longitude_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | HBAL102 | -4.82114 | -76.3194 | -4.5249 | -79.0103 |
| 1 | AUA1028 | -33.9635 | 151.181 | 48.1174 | 16.55 |
| 2 | ABW120 | 41.9659 | -87.8832 | 55.9835 | 37.4958 |
| 3 | CSN461 | 33.9363 | -118.414 | 50.0357 | 8.5723 |
| 4 | ETH3730 | 25.3864 | 55.4221 | 50.6342 | 5.43903 |

But unfortunately, I would get an incorrect result when creating LineString with shapely. I used everything like rotate and affine but it didn't correct.

Code:

```py
cols = pd.read_csv("/content/dirct_lines.csv",sep=";")

line = cols[["callsign","latitude_1","longitude_1","latitude_2","longitude_2"]].dropna()

line['geometry'] = line.apply(lambda x: [(x['latitude_1'],
                                                         x['longitude_1']),
                                                         (x['latitude_2'],
                                                          x['longitude_2'])], axis = 1)
geoline = gpd.GeoDataFrame(line,geometry="geometry",
                      crs="EPSG:4326")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

ax = world.plot(figsize=(14,9),
    color='white', edgecolor='black')

geoline.plot(figsize=(14,9),ax=ax,facecolor = 'lightgrey', linewidth = 1.75,
           edgecolor = 'red',
           alpha = 2)
plt.show()
```

[Shapely Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mut9L.png)

something that was interesting for me was that when I use Matplotlib to create lines everything is correct.

Code:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))


ax = fig.add_subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())


ax.stock_img()

org_lon, org_lat = cols["longitude_1"], cols["latitude_1"]
dst_lon, dst_lat = cols["longitude_2"], cols["latitude_2"]


plt.plot([org_lon, dst_lon], [org_lat, dst_lat],
        color='black', linewidth=0.5, marker='_',
        transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()
        )


plt.savefig(f"fight_path.png",dpi=60,facecolor = None, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = None)
plt.show()
```

[Matplotlib Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCi7F.png)

What is the problem?

why isn't correct by shapely?

Comment: Check lat/lon order, many libraries prefer lon/lat order instead, see e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376751/shapely-flips-lat-long-coordinate

Comment: Thankful, yes when I changed them, everything worked,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just the way you are creating the geometry.  Below works correctly.

```
import io
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import shapely.geometry

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """callsign,latitude_1,longitude_1,latitude_2,longitude_2
HBAL102,-4.82114,-76.3194,-4.5249,-79.0103
AUA1028,-33.9635,151.181,48.1174,16.55
ABW120,41.9659,-87.8832,55.9835,37.4958
CSN461,33.9363,-118.414,50.0357,8.5723
ETH3730,25.3864,55.4221,50.6342,5.43903
"""
    )
)

geoline = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.LineString(points)
        for points in zip(
            gpd.points_from_xy(df["longitude_1"], df["latitude_1"]),
            gpd.points_from_xy(df["longitude_2"], df["latitude_2"]),
        )
    ],
    data=df,
)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
ax = world.plot(figsize=(14, 9), color="white", edgecolor="black")

geoline.plot(
    figsize=(14, 9),
    ax=ax,
    facecolor="lightgrey",
    linewidth=1.75,
    edgecolor="red",
)
plt.show()
```